# Loss of DNS on BeagleBone Black Debian

Tags: debian, dns, dnsmasq, beagleboneblack

We are running a remote application on a beaglebone black in which we regularly report our external ip address retrieved from various external ip services (freegeoip.net, ipinfo.io, various STUN servers, etc.)

At one location, when we lose internet but the device stays powered up, once the internet connectivity is restored, we lose our ability to perform DNS queries. A direct google ip address can be pinged but `www.google.com` is unsuccessful. I have tested and poked and prodded at a number of things, and this is all I can say for certain. I haven't seen this at other locations but right now we are also only at a handful of sites so it's possible it just hasn't shown up yet.

- Restarting the device resolves the issue
- Restarting `connman` resolves the issue
- Manually adding a line in `/etc/resolv.conf` to point to the default gateway or google DNS services resolves the issues

Right now it appears that /`etc/resolv.conf` is managed by connman (as it is merely a symlink to `/var/run/connman/resolv.conf`)

Can/should I be using an alternate DNS Service (e.g. `dnsmasq`) or perhaps should I totally ditch the "intelligent" config services in favor of the more reliable if more programmatically tedious manual file configuration (i.e. manually write gateway and localhost to `/etc/resolv.conf` and /etc/network/interfaces)

EDIT: Version information

Debian version: Debian GNU/Linux 8 \n \l

BeagleBoard.org Debian Image 2016-12-09

connmand --version: 1.33

dnsmasq --version: 2.72

Comment: I ditch them on my VMs....KISS